# How to have a default value for the not found keys in a map in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have three classes a,b, and c. All inherit the same class, and I have to select which class to use during runtime on the basis of a key.

Here is the Spring code I wrote:

```
 <bean id="ConfigurationAdapterMap" class="abc">
   <property name="adapterMap">
       <map>
        <entry key="key1">
          <bean class="class1"/>
        </entry>
        <entry key="Other">
          <bean class="class2"/>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </property>     
  </bean>
```

I don't want to pass 'Other' explicitly, and I want to return class2, if the given key does not match any key in the keyset. Can I get spring to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
You can also explicitly control the exact type of Map that will be 
instantiated and populated via the use of the 'map-class' 
attribute on the  element.
```

So, for example, you can take `DefaultedMap` from `commons-collections` and try to use it as `map-class`. Or you can implement your own `Map` and use it.

Comment: How can we do it with spring ?